# Access Nested Object Inside Array in Angular NGXS

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

I have successfully implemented the delete comment function in my Angular app. My problem now is on the liking function of the comment. How do i implement the like function. I have the variable is_liked to determine if its like or not. The value = 0 means its not like and the value = 1 is liked.
Pls see my stackblitz link here

[PLS CLICK THIS LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-delete-like)

```
onLikeComment(data: Comment) {
    this.store.dispatch(new LikeComment(data)).subscribe();
  }

@Action(LikeComment)
  likeComment(
    ctx: StateContext<PostStateModel>,
    { payload }: LikeComment
  ) {
    if (payload.is_liked === 1) {
      payload.is_liked = 0;
    } else {
      payload.is_liked = 1;
    }
    const state = ctx.getState();
    ctx.setState(
      patch({
        post: {
          ...state.post,
          comments: [
            ...state.post.comments,
            updateItem<any>(name => name === payload.id, payload)
          ]
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Updates to the state should be [immutable'ish](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/state#actions-with-a-payload), instead of directly updating data, as you do with `is_liked` property

Comment: @Yurii. Can you help me out? Can you edit my stackblitz? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem you have in your code is the use of the `updateItem` state operator. This operator needs to be assigned to the field in the object you pass to the `patch` operator.

```
patch({
  field1: 'someValue',
  comments: updateItem<Comment>(
    comment => comment.id === 0,
    {id: 0, text: 'This is a nice post!', is_liked: 1}
  )
})
```

[updateItem Reference](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/packages/store/operators/src/update-item.ts#L12)

The second problem I see with your action handler is that you're not using the patch operator correctly. This operator allows to only assign the values to the fields you want to change like `StateContext.patchState`.

I would change your code to this:

```
  @Action(LikeComment)
  likeComment(
    ctx: StateContext<PostStateModel>,
    { payload }: LikeComment
  ) {
    const isLiked = payload.is_liked === 1 ? 0 : 1;

    ctx.setState(
      patch({
        // Apply patch on the post to only update the comments field
        post: patch({
          // Apply updateItem to make the operator only update the item that matches the condition
          comments: updateItem<Comment>(
            comment => comment.id === payload.id,
            // Apply a patch on the found comment to only change the is_liked field.
            patch({is_liked: isLiked}))
        })
      })
    );
  }
```

Hope this makes sense. It's my first answer on SO :)

Here's the [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-delete-like-h2m1hq)

Comment: How does it know which post to get? And comments would be an array right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to NGXS but I was able to do this by playing with the built-in operators. At this stage I do not believe adding immutability tooling, like Immer, is needed.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
const jobs = [
  {
    id: 0,
    tasks: [
      {
        id: 0,
        status: 'To Do',
        ...
      }
  ... 
  }
]
```

Here is the action that updates the nested object:

```
  @Action(SetJob)
  setTask(ctx: StateContext<JobsStateModel>, { payload }: SetJob) {
    ctx.setState(
      patch({
        jobs: updateItem((item: any) => item.status === payload.status, patch({ tasks: insertItem(payload, 1) })),
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can handle the 'like' function as follows.

```
ctx.setState(
      patch({
        post: {
          ...state.post,
          comments: this.getUpdatedComments(state, payload)
        }
      })
    );
```

---

```
getUpdatedComments(state, payload): any {
      let comments = [];
      state.post.comments.forEach((cmt) => {
          if (cmt.id === payload.id) {
              cmt = Object.assign({}, cmt);
              cmt.is_liked = payload.is_liked === 1 ? 0 : 1;
          }
          comments.push(cmt);
      });
      return comments;
  }
```

Here is the updated demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-delete-like-dek3s1.

Comment: Thanks for this but your mutating the state. Can you revise it by not mutating the state and by using the State Operators by NGXS? Thanks